# What's function in C# equivalent to CreateObject in Vb6

Tags: c#, object, vb6, siebel

VB6 Code:

```
Dim oApplication As SiebelHTMLApplication
Dim oBS As SiebelService
Dim oPSIn As SiebelPropertySet
Dim oPSOut As SiebelPropertySet
Dim sActivityId As String
Set oApplication = CreateObject("Siebel.Desktop_Integration_Application.1")
If oApplication.IsReady Then
    Set oBS = oApplication.GetService("Workflow Process Manager")
```

C# Code :-

```
SiebelHTMLApplication sApp = new SiebelHTMLApplication();
SiebelService sService = new SiebelService();
SiebelPropertySet sPsIn = new SiebelPropertySet();
SiebelPropertySet sPsOut = new SiebelPropertySet();
```

Then I try to convert line#6 of VB code to c# as :-

```
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Siebel.Desktop_Integration_Application.1"));
```

but I couldn't casting instance object to SiebelHTMLApplication like :-

```
sApp = (SiebelHTMLApplication)instance;
```

Can any one suggest me an idea how to set it ?

Answer (score 2):

Type.GetTypeFromProgID creates the com instance but not the Type object.

Try

```
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Siebel.Desktop_Integration_Application, AssemblyName"));
```

You have to replace AssemblyName with the name of the Assembly which contains the Siebel.Desktop_Integration_Application description.

Comment: Thanks for replied, you're exactly right.

Then when I changed from object to type with Type.GetTypeFromProgID. It should work

Answer (score 0):

You could always import Microsoft.VisualBasic and then just use [CreateObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t9k08y5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) ?

Comment: @PattadonBanthoonipit: the Microsoft.VisualBasic library is not VB code (either VB6 or .NET) it is simply another library in the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to Vasiliy, Finally I got the solution by changing from object to type. Then It's working now !!

```
var siebelDeskType = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Siebel.Desktop_Integration_Application.1"));
            sApp = (SiebelHTMLApplication)siebelDeskType;
```